# In D, how do I specify a variadic template constraint on all the whole tuple?

Tags: variadic-templates, d

I'm writing 2 overloads of a function, both of them with variadic template compile-time parameters. One should take symbols as the templates, the other strings. I want to constrain the template instantiation to these two cases. The best I came up with was this:

```
bool func(SYMBOLS...)() if(!is(typeof(SYMBOLS[0]) == string)) {
}
```

and

```
bool func(STRINGS...)() if(is(typeof(STRINGS[0]) == string)) {
}
```

Obviously this only checks the first template parameter, and while it works given the code I've written so far, I wish I could say "only for all strings" and "only for not all strings". Is there a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works (from http://forum.dlang.org/thread/qyosftfkxadeypzvtvpk@forum.dlang.org with help from Andrej Mitrovic):

```
import std.traits;
import std.typetuple;

void runTests(SYMBOLS...)() if(!anySatisfy!(isSomeString, typeof(SYMBOLS))) {
}

void runTests(STRINGS...)() if(allSatisfy!(isSomeString, typeof(STRINGS))) {
}
```

Comment: Wow - that is much cleaner. :) It's nice to know that you can stick an anonymous function inside the if statement though.

Answer (score 6):

It took me a while to figure it out, but here is a potential solution to your problem:

```
module main;

import std.stdio;

int main(string[] argv)
{
    bool test1PASS = func(1,2,3,4,5.5, true);
    //bool test2CTE = func(1,2,3,4,5, true, "CRAP");
    bool test3PASS = func("CRAP", "3", "true");
    //bool test4CTE = func("CRAP", "3", "true", 42, true, 6.5);

    return 0;
}

bool func(NOSTRINGS...)(NOSTRINGS x) 
    if ({foreach(t; NOSTRINGS) if (is(t == string)) return false; return true; }()) {

    // code here ...
    return true;
}

bool func(ONLYSTRINGS...)(ONLYSTRINGS x) 
    if ({foreach(t; ONLYSTRINGS) if (!is(t == string)) return false; return true; }()) {

    // code here ...
    return true;
}
```